How Can I acheive one-to-many communication between emulated Bluetooth controllers using bt-virt
I have a requirement that there is a sender (virtually emulated one) that has to transmit to two different virtually emulated bluetooth controllers.How can this be acheived?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for the reply. I have a sender/transmitter and 2 receivers which has to communicate using Bluetooth. The three modules are actually the local controllers emulated by BT-virt. My requirement is the sender has to send data to the two receivers simulatenously (something like one-to-many model), How can I acheive it?

please add that to your post
